# Is it possible to align and labels inputs from a form using JavaScript and HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, alignment

Just started studying **JavaScript** and **HTML5** for my diploma and I am currently having some trouble trying to figure out how to ***align*** the ***inputs*** within the form so they ***align*** nicely along with the ***labels*** as well.

Also trying to stray away from using any **CSS**.

Would be grateful for any advice or comments received.

```js
var formStyle=document.getElementById("formStyle");//creates variable and links it to the form
formStyle.style.fontFamily="Arial";//sets font for within the form
formStyle.style.borderStyle = "outset";//gives border that procedes to make the form look 3D
formStyle.style.padding = "10px";//sets padding within form
formStyle.style.width = "350px";//sets form width
formStyle.style.backgroundColor="lightblue";//changes background colour of form

function changeBgd(textField)
{
 textField.style.background="lightgrey";//when text field is selected it will change colour to represent it has been selected by the user
}

function resetBgd(textField)
{
 textField.style.background="";//resets currently selected text field to original colour when deselected
}

function buttonHelp()
{
 window.open("\helpassignment.html");//opens help page in seperate tab
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>
4JSB Assignment
</title>
</head>
<body onload="styleBody()">
<div class="container">
<center> <!--aligns form to centre of page-->
<form name="donationform" id="formStyle" onsubmit="validateDonation()"/>
<label id="labels">First Name:</label>
<input id="inputs" type="text" name="firstname" onfocus="changeBgd(this)" onblur="resetBgd(this)" required/><br/><br/>
<label id="labels">Last Name:</label>
<input id="inputs" type="text" name="lastname" onfocus="changeBgd(this)" onblur="resetBgd(this)" required/><br/><br/>
<label id="labels">Email Address:</label>
<input id="inputs" type="email" name="email"  pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z].{2,4}$" onfocus="changeBgd(this)" onblur="resetBgd(this)" required /><br/><br/>
<label id="labels">Postcode:</label>
<input id="inputs" type="text" name="postcode" pattern="[0-9]{4}" maxlength="4" onfocus="changeBgd(this)" onblur="resetBgd(this)" required/><br/><br/>
<label id="labels">Donation:</label>
<input id="inputs" type="text" name="donationamount" value="$0" onfocus="changeBgd(this)" onblur="resetBgd(this)" required/><br/><br/>
<label id="labels">Credit Card:</label>
<select id="inputs">
   <option value="0">Visa</option>
   <option value="1">MasterCard</option>
   <option value="2">American Express</option>
   </select><br/><br/>
<label id="labels">Card Number:</label>
<input id="inputs" type="text" name="cardnum" pattern="[0-9]{16}" maxlength="16" onfocus="changeBgd(this)" onblur="resetBgd(this)" required/><br/><br/>
<label id="labels">CCV:</label>
<input id="inputs" type="text" name="ccv" pattern="[0-9]{3}" maxlength="3" onfocus="changeBgd(this)" onblur="resetBgd(this)" required/><br/><br/>
<label id="labels">Expiry Date:</label>
<select id="inputs">
   <option value="0">Select Month</option>
   <option value="1">January</option>
   <option value="2">Feburary</option>
   <option value="3">March</option>
   <option value="4">April</option>
   <option value="5">May</option>
   <option value="6">June</option>
   <option value="7">July</option>
   <option value="8">August</option>
   <option value="9">September</option>
   <option value="10">October</option>
   <option value="11">November</option>
   <option value="12">December</option>
   </select>
   <select id="inputs">
   <option value="0">Select Year</option>
   <option value="1">2017</option>
   <option value="2">2018</option>
   <option value="3">2019</option>
   <option value="4">2020</option>
   <option value="5">2021</option>
   <option value="6">2022</option>
   </select><br/><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="buttonHelp()" value="Help"> <!--provides link to help page-->
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset"><!--provides reset button for user to clear form-->
</form>
</center>
</div>
<script src="..\js\assignment.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try with [`table tag`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiShb_vyY_UAhXFo48KHVsKDzsQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Ftags%2Ftag_table.asp&usg=AFQjCNH3xxemDTwdaHvqHxfDHggDUB0-DQ&sig2=kFaT7VgGQ6JBQaDrhtg91A) .you will get the correct alignment

Answer (score 0):

for change att for each element use this (with **javascript**(***jquery***)):

```
 $(your element).att('att name','att variabel);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set a new att call `placeholder`  use like this :

```
<input type='text' placeholder='name' id='name' class='name' />
```

now it will wite a 'name' at field and when user click it dissappered.